# Make size of external graphics 100% to fill a polygon

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I have a layer that is comprised of a number of different polygons and want to symbolize dynamically using the database.
I have achieved this but the issue is in styling the image in the polygon is not fitting it is repeating when I zoom in.
I want to fit the image fit in the polygon when I zoom in or out.

Comment: Here is the SLD that i am using now
<Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://map-logos/${image_url}.png" />
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>Auto</Size>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

Comment: Please do not comment on your own Question. Instead, [Edit] the question and delete the comment

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as complete auto-scaling... what you could do may be to set the image size in [ground units](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/uom.html), so that when you zoom in, the size of the image also increases.
That said, with a PNG the results of upscaling would look pretty bad (pixellated or blurry). A SVG image might give you better results.

Generally speaking, when using image fills, it's a good idea to make sure the images are [seamless background images](https://pixabay.com/images/search/seamless%20background/) (that is, images that can be replicated on each side and will not show any interruption).